# Get groups of elements from string array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, loops

I have an array with strings that I want to parse through to make objects of each group of 4 strings. Can this be done with a for-loop?

The only thing identifying a group is that each group will contain 4 strings.

The array looks like this, where the top value "NumberOfItemsInArray" will be a number telling how many item-groups follows. The number of items is dynamic.

```
NumberOfItemsInArray
Item1-Name
Item1-Price
Item1-DiscountRate
Item1-Category
Item2-Name
Item2-Price
Item2-DiscountRate
Item2-Category
```

Is there any way to do this cleanly?

Comment: Please **clarify your specific problem** or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Basically I want to loop through an array that looks like the one described and get every group of 4 strings to a new separate array. How do you do this with a for-loop?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Describe the array in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming you have some constructor for YourObject that takes the 4 strings (a,b,c,d), it should be fairly simple, given your input string array, MyArray, and an output `List<YourObject>` YourObjectList :

```
int iItems = System.Convert.ToInt32(MyArray[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < iItems; i+=4)
    YourObjectList.Add( new YourObject( MyArray[i+1], MyArray[i+2], MyArray[i+3], MyArray[i+4] ) );
```

That should be about right - haven't run it through a compiler, though
- John

Answer (score 0):

Determine the number of groups of four based on the length of your array. Then just iterate through the original array, and fill the array of groups of four.

```
    string[] itemsArray = { "8", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };

    int nGroups = (itemsArray.Length - 1) / 4;
    string[][] groups = new string[nGroups][];

    for (int i = 0; i < nGroups; i++) {
        print("- new group of four -"); 
        groups[i] = new string[4];
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            groups[i][j] = itemsArray[i * 4 + j + 1];
            print(groups[i][j]); 
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
- new group of four -
a
b
c
d
- new group of four -
e
f
g
h
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NumberOfItemsInArray` looks quite useless, since you have the `Array.Lenght`, and I think that your array is not array, I think it is dictionary, if so then look at this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Program {
    class _Main {
        // Initialize dictionary with values
        static Dictionary<string, string> dictionaryWithStrings = new Dictionary<string, string> { 
            { "NumberOfItemsInArray", "2" },
            { "Item1-Name", "Some name" },
            { "Item1-Price", "0.5$" },
            { "Item1-DiscountRate", "?%" },
            { "Item1-Category", "Some category" },
            { "Item2-Name", "Other name" },
            { "Item2-Price", "4$" },
            { "Item2-DiscountRate", "24%" },
            { "Item2-Category", "Other category" }
        };
        // Create *dynamic* list with Item's
        static List<Item> objects = new List<Item>();
        static void Main() {            
            // "- 1" removes the NumberOfItemsInArray from count
            // "/ 4" Since you have always 4 strings
            for (int i = 1; i <= (dictionaryWithStrings.Count - 1) / 4; i++) {
                objects.Add(new Item {
                    Name = dictionaryWithStrings["Item"+i+"-Name"],
                    Price = dictionaryWithStrings["Item"+i+"-Price"],
                    DiscountRate = dictionaryWithStrings["Item"+i+"-DiscountRate"],
                    Category = dictionaryWithStrings["Item"+i+"-Category"] 
                });
            }
            Console.WriteLine("objects contains [" + objects.Count + "] items, values:");
            foreach (Item item in objects) {
                Console.WriteLine("Item id: [" + objects.IndexOf(item) + 
                    "], Name: [" + item.Name +
                    "], Price: [" + item.Price + 
                    "], DiscountRate: [" + item.DiscountRate + 
                    "], Category: [" +item.Category + "]"
                );
            }
        }
        struct Item {
            public string Name;
            public string Price;
            public string DiscountRate;
            public string Category;
        }
    }
}
```